# Custom treeSet class, how to write iterator

Tags: java, iterator, treeset

I am trying to create my own binary search tree. But I can't think of any way to implement a working iterator that has hasNext(), next().
I got the idea the only way to traverse a Binary search tree was through recursion. But how could I possibly save a recursion call if I am trying to use next, so it resumes when next gets called again and returns the value?
Is there any other way

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TreeWordSet implements WordSetInterface {
    private BST root = null;

    private class BST {
        Word value;
        BST left = null;
        BST right = null;

        BST(Word word) {
            value = word;
        }

        void add(Word newWord) {
            if (newWord.compareTo(value) < 0) {
                if(left == null) {
                    left = new BST(newWord);
                } else {
                    left.add(newWord);
                }
            } else if (newWord.compareTo(value) > 0) {
                if (right == null) {
                    right = new BST(newWord);
                } else {
                    right.add(newWord);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Word word) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new BST(word);
        } else {
            root.add(word);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Word word) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    private class TreeWordSetIterator implements Iterator<Word> {

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Word next() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Word> iterator() {
        return new TreeWordSetIterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if it would be the most correct way to do it, but I think the easiest way is to recurse the tree into a Collection and then return the collection's iterator.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an exercise for the purpose of learning, maybe the best way is to just go look how TreeSet does it.  If this is an exercise for production use, stop it right here right now and extend TreeSet if you really need to.

Comment: It's an exercise. I have been looking at how the class does it. But it seems much more complex and uneceserialy robust for what I am trying to do. I don't understand it. I am trying to make a more simple iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, it's not glamourous. Until someone can provide a better solution

```
    private class TreeWordSetIterator implements Iterator<Word> {
    Word arr[] = new Word[size()];
    int i = 0;
    TreeWordSetIterator(){
        traverse(root);
        i = 0;
    }

    private void traverse(BST currentNode) {
        if (currentNode == null) {
            return;
        }
        traverse(currentNode.left);
        arr[i] = currentNode.value;
        i++;
        traverse(currentNode.right);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (i < size()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Word next() {
        Word current = arr[i];
        i++;
        return current;

    }
}
```

Comment: An _efficient_ iterator (which yours isn't) needs to capture the state of an efficient search as it discovers each element. The state more-or-less consists of a stack of nodes that were encountered while descending along left child pointers to the current node.